# PHP: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Help me solve this error

php script:

> error found in line that contains $stmt->execute($params)

```
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$passwd = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'passwd', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

// bind parameter ke query
$params = array(
    ":username" => $username

);

$stmt->execute($params);

$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: How is your connection initialized? Which is the message of the Exception thrown?

Answer (score -3):

**You can try this**

```
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$passwd = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'passwd', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam('username',$username);
$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Since it seems to be `$db->prepare($sql)` that returns false instead of a statement, this would just give your _"Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean"_ instead. You've only moved the error.